# Connect two div using polyline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've multiple small `div` elements. I want to create connection between them. like user first select 1st `div` then next `div` and connection between these two is created by line. I saw a very nice [Example](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/wrapped/flowchart/index.html) here. but it's too expensive, and at this moment my requirements are not too high. Just connecting multiple `div` is okay. I'm using JQuery in AngularJS 4.

How can I do this, any hint, idea?

Comment: Probably should look into using the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).